# Multiple executables as a single file

Tags: python, bash, scripting, path, packing

For some routine work I found that combining different scripting languages can be the fastest way to do. Like I have some main bash script which calles some awk, pyton and bash scripts or even some compiled fortran executables.

I can put all the files into a folder that is in the paths, but it makes modification is a bit slower. If I need a new copy with some modifications I need to add another path to $PATH as well.

Is there a way to make merge these files as a single executable?

For example: tar all the files together and explain somehow that the main script is main.sh? This way I could simply vi the file, modify, run, modify, run ... but I could move the file between folders and machines easily. Also dependencies could be handle properly (executing the tar could set PATH itself).

I hope this dream does exist! Thanks for the comments!

Janos

Comment: Since you are using Bash, you can have a script calling each one of them, or even piping them. However, I doubt using different languages to split a task is the best approach in general: most likely you can find a good one in which you can do all of it.

Answer (score 0):

From a software engineering point of view, this approach does not sound so great because your programs would be be badly structured by design (but maybe that is no problem in your case). Also, you will lose syntax highlighting support in your editor when combining multiple languages in one file. I would rather suggest building a package of all your programs, distributing them 
together, and after deployment have the main script call the other programs.

That being said, you could use [here documents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) in Bash, see `bash(1)` (search for "Here Documents"), to include other text scripts in your main script, then have the main script write them to a temporary directory and execute them. This will not help you with your compiled code though, unless you have a compiler on your target machine.

This [Linux Journal Article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/add-binary-payload-your-shell-scripts) might be interesting for you too, as it shows how to include a binary payload (e.g. a tgz file) in a Bash script. You could use this to add a compressed archive containing your programs to a never-changing main script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers!

Of course this is not a good approach for providing a published code! Sorry if it was confusing. But this is a good approach if you are developing some e.g. scientific idea, and you wish to obtain a proof of concept result fast and you wish to do similar tasks several times but replacing fast some parts of the algorithm. Note, that sometimes many codes are available for some parts of the task. These codes are sometimes needed to be modified a bit (a few lines). I am a big believer of re-implementing everything, but first it is good to know if it worth to do!

For some compromise: can I call a script externally that is wrapped in some tar or zip and is not compressed?

Thanks again,

J.